# Integer storage and use it in a method

Tags: ios, integer, global-variables, nsuserdefaults, store

I want to store an integer and use it in random method. But integer that i stored always show wrong value. When it should be 2, it shows 1. When it should be 7, it shows 6.

When i call random method second time without any increase, it shows what it should be. It looks like a delay to me.

I tried to use global variable but the conclusion was same.

```
if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown){

   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   if(_slot1.tag == 20){
      int i = (int)[defaults integerForKey:@"pro"];
      i++;
      [defaults setInteger:i forKey:@"pro"];
      [defaults synchronize];
   }

[self random];

}

-(void)random{
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   int i = (int)[defaults integerForKey:@"pro"];

   NSLog(@"PRO: %d",i);

   if(i==0 || i==1){
      .......
   }
}
```

Comment: Remove synchronize & then try..But i tried your NSUserDefaults logic  its perfect , added user defaults logic on button click on first click its showing me 1 , on second 2 & so on ...

Comment: Do you need to persist this value between executions of your app?  If not, then NSUserDefaults ins't the right approach - You should use a property

Comment: @KrunalDarji Same problem goes on.

Comment: @Paulw11 How can i achieve that with property? Can you explain briefly please?

Comment: @KrunalDarji I don't know mate. it is really weird. it always shows me the previous value.

Comment: At the top of the .m file after the #import and before the @implementation add `@interface YourClassName () @property int pro; @end` (each of those on a separate line) then you can use self.pro to refer to it.

Comment: do one thing remove your app from simulator , add one button & on press of it increment i value & call random method

Comment: What is `_slot1.tag` and what debugging have you done? Is the code all called and when you expect?